# Tienes 5 intentos para adivinar un número pero al estos acabarse sigue dando oportunidades

Tags: c#

```
        Random num = new Random();
        int anyNum = num.Next(0,20);

        int userNum;
        int intentos = 5;

        Console.WriteLine("Adivina el numero entre 0 y 20");
        userNum = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        if (userNum == anyNum){
            Console.WriteLine($"{anyNum} Es el numero correcto. ¡Felicidades!");
        } else{
            while(userNum != anyNum){
                if (intentos == 0){

                    intentos--;
                    Console.WriteLine("El número es incorrecto");
                    Console.WriteLine($"Te quedan {intentos} intentos");

                    Console.WriteLine("Haz agotado tus intentos");
                    Console.WriteLine($"El numero es {anyNum}");
                } else if(intentos == 0){
                    Console.WriteLine("Sigue intentando");
                    userNum = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                }
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine($"{anyNum} Es el numero correcto. ¡Felicidades!");
        Console.WriteLine("Gracias por participar");
```

Answer (score 0):

mira esto

```
while(userNum != anyNum){
                if (intentos == 0){

                    intentos--;
                    Console.WriteLine("El número es incorrecto");
                    Console.WriteLine($"Te quedan {intentos} intentos");

                    Console.WriteLine("Haz agotado tus intentos");
                    Console.WriteLine($"El numero es {anyNum}");
                } else if(intentos == 0){
                    Console.WriteLine("Sigue intentando");
                    userNum = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                }
            }
```

tu falla esta en que ambos if tienen la condicion ==0

podrias poner esto dentro del while

```
if(intentos==0){
 Console.WriteLine("sin intentos");
}else{
intentos--
Console.WriteLine("El número es incorrecto");
}
```

Comment: Gracias pero tampoco me funciono

Comment: que te imprime en consola?

Comment: pero como te digo tienes que revisar la condicion de ambos if, ahi esta tu falla

Comment: En consola imprimía el mensaje: sin intentos y lo hacia indefinidamente, solo cerrando la consola se detenia

Comment: Ya rehice el código y logre hacerlo mejor esta vez y resolver el problema

Answer (score 0):

Logre resolver el problema reescribiendo el código

int adivinar = 24;
            int intentos = 0;
            int num;

```
        Console.WriteLine("Escribe un número entre 0 y 50");
        num = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        intentos++;

        while (num != adivinar && intentos <= 5){

            if (num != adivinar){
                Console.WriteLine("Número incorrecto");
            }

            if (intentos < 5){
            Console.WriteLine("Intenta de nuevo");
            Console.WriteLine($"Llevas {intentos} intentos");
            num = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            } else if (intentos == 5){
                Console.WriteLine("Haz agotado tus intentos");
                Console.WriteLine($"El número correcto es {adivinar}");
            }
        }

        if (num == adivinar){
        Console.WriteLine("Número correcto");
        Console.WriteLine($"Haz acertado el número con {intentos} intentos");
        }
```